# Transformar um array em um json sem as chaves

Tags: php

Eu preciso que um array assim:

$dados["elemento"][0] => ["disciplina" => "aleatorio"];

$dados["elemento"][1] => ["disciplina" => "aleatorio2"];

$dados["elemento"][2] => ["disciplina" => "aleatorio3"];

$dados["elemento"][3] => ["disciplina" => "aleatorio4"];

quando utilziar um json_encode fique

"elemento":[{"disciplina": "aleatorio"},{"disciplina": "aleatorio2"},{"disciplina": "aleatorio3"}]

atualmente fica assim:

"elemento":["0": {"disciplina": "aleatorio"},"1": {"disciplina": "aleatorio2"},"2": {"disciplina": "aleatorio3"}]

Comment: Tem certeza? Aqui ficou da forma como você gostaria: https://ideone.com/tgO5OB. Consegue gerar um [mcve]?

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, o correto sempre é editar a [pergunta original](/q/591083/3635), ajustando o entendimento ou corrigindo problemas. O campo de comentários aqui foi bloqueado, para que todos participantes continuem em apenas um lugar, na pergunta original.